# C++ STL Stack What can forward order mean?

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, stack

> Implement the read-and-correct algorithm as a C++ function, but make the stack local to the function instead of an argument. Let the function construct a string that contains the corrected input characters in **forward order**, and return it. Use C++ Standard Template Library (STL) stack.

Thats the context, what does **forward order** mean?

So far my code outputs this

```
Enter a string : hadjkv
The corrected input characters in forward order : hjkv
```

It first I thought it was from ASCII order.

Maybe its in ASCII order but my code may have logic problems, still I'm clueless to the meaning of **forward order**.

Comment: I would advise you to ask your teacher.

Comment: The opposite of reverse order

Comment: I'm not sure if an answer can be given without knowing which corrections are being made to the input. If I were to "meta" the question, I would guess that the reason the problem specified "forward" order is that naive use of a stack would tend to (or at least be reasonably likely to) produce reversed order. Maybe just look at your output and see if it might be considered "reversed" in some sense?

Answer (score 0):

This perhaps means you should remove characters from the string that are not in forward order.

- `hadjkv` - the first char is always in forward order.
- `hdjkv` - drop a.
- `hjkv` - drop d.

Other chars are in order.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, in that sense my code is correct. I asked my professor to see if I get an answer, but the professor takes almost a week to respond.

Edit:
I tried with a different input and got:

Enter a string : quiopalj
The corrected input characters in forward order : qu